# Counting the number of cities in the given list made up of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

*'data' is a list made-up of dictionaries. enter code hereI want to count the number of 'City' present in 'data' list without using a loop.*

```
data = [{'City': 'Solta', 'Country': 'Croatia'},
 {'City': 'Greenville', 'Country': 'USA'},
 {'City': 'Buenos Aires', 'Country': 'Argentina'},
 {'City': 'Los Cabos', 'Country': 'Mexico'}]

'''
#This code is working
count = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    if('City' in data[i].keys()):
        count = count+1
print('No of Cities: ',count)
'''
```

## **I want to know, Is there any other way to calculate no. of cities in it, without using a loop??**

Comment: Is the answer just `len(data)`?

Comment: `>>> sum(1 for x in data if 'City' in x)` would return `4`

Comment: @karlosss let's suppose there is no city in the data[0]

Comment: What if the value of `City` is more than one in a dict? E.g. `{'City': ['A','B'], 'Country': 'Croatia'}`

Comment: Why make that assumption? You data is not consistent? If it is, then answer @karlosss gave works, I guess.

Comment: `sum(1 if isinstance(x['City'], str) else len(x.get('City', []))  for x in data)` should work if you have 'City' `value` as `str` or some iterable like `list` or `tuple` :)

Comment: In that case please describe your data structure better. I have no idea what you want to hear from us. And by the way, what is wrong with `for`?

Answer (score 0):

it's easy.use this:

```
len(data)
```

it will give you length of list.